# Using head() to print n ordered rows in dataframe from random starting position

Tags: r

I know I can use

```
head(sample(x),m)
```

to print a random selection of *m* rows from my dataset, but in this case each new draw is randomized. What if, instead of randomizing every draw, I wanted to randomize only the starting position for the first draw, while preserving the order of subsequent rows?

To illustrate, imagine we have a dataset of *n* rows and I wanted to print *m* of them in order, starting from a random position. The randomly drawn starting position is 5, so my desired function would print **5, 6, 7, ..., *m*** < *n*.

This is more of a theoretical question, not a diagnostic one, so I don't believe a MWE example is needed...please let me know if you think it is and I will be happy to provide one.

Comment: perhaps this helps `df1[sample(nrow(df1), 1) + 0:3,]`

Comment: @akrun solution was so simple. If you put it in an answer I will select it.

Comment: A slight modification is `i1 <-  sample(nrow(df1), 1)+ 0:3; df1[ i1[i1 <= nrow(df1)], ]` for some edge cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a numeric index using the `sample` element and adding with the sequence of 'n' rows that should follow it.  If the `sample`d index is say the last row, then we can create a condition to check for those cases

```
i1 <- sample(nrow(df1), 1)+ 0:3
df1[ i1[i1 <= nrow(df1)], ]
```

Comment: Or use 'nrow(df1)-m' to account for those edge cases